# foci of the smallest ellipse passing through 3 given points

Tags: geometry

I would like a formula for the foci of the smallest ellipse passing through a set of 3 given points. For example, say we have points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3)$ , there will be a unique smallest ellipse (where by smallest I mean smallest area). I would like to know the locations of the foci for this ellipse. Thanks,

Mathew

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerCircumellipse.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BickartPoints.html

Comment: @Rahul I see we were on the same "wavelength" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward way to find this smallest ellipse (that we will call "circumscribed" to the triangle) by considering the issue with complex numbers. For a full explanation, see this [nice article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/15d4/55b5aaa6a36f28156efbd38e6a3af6e48fa9.pdf) (Mathematics Mag. 86 (2013) 136-143.)

Here is how it works.

Let $z_k=x_k+iy_k, k=1,2,3$. Let us denote by $T$ the triangle with vertices $z_k$ in the complex plane. Consider the third degree polynomial

$$f(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)\tag{1}$$

The 2 roots of quadratic equation

$$f'(z)=0 \ \iff \ 3z^2-2\underbrace{(z_1+z_2+z_3)}_{S}z+\underbrace{(z_1z_2+z_2z_3+z_3z_1)}_{R}=0\tag{2}$$

are shown to be the (complex numbers associated with) the foci of an inscribed ellipse which is known as the **Steiner ellipse** (ellipse with smallest area **inscribed into** triangle $T$, with the property that it passes through the 3 midpoints of triangle $T$). From there, it suffices to take an homothety (= enlargment) with ratio $2$ centered into the ellipse's center (which is as well the center of gravity of triangle $T$) to find the ellipse with smallest area that is **circumscribed to** triangle $T$.

**Edit :**

The explicit solutions of (2) are :

$$f_1=(S-\sqrt{D})/3, \ \ \ f_2=(S+\sqrt{D})/3 \ \ \text{where} \ D:=S^2-3R$$

(take care : $\pm\sqrt{D}$ is to be understood as any root of complex equation $z^2=D$). 
$f_1$ and $f_2$ are the foci of the **inscribed** ellipse in triangle $T$.

It remains to do the enlargment, finally giving the foci of the circumscribed ellipse :

> $$F_1=g-h, F_2=g+h \ \  \text{with} \ \ g:=\tfrac{f_1+f_2}{2}, h:=f_1-f_2 $$

[image]

*Fig. 1 : Right image : The two Steiner ellipses (inscribed and circumscribed). They have been obtained plainly as the images of the left figure through transformation $z \ \to z':=z+a \bar{z}$ for a certain $a$. Stars indicate the foci of the inscribed ellipse which can be shown to be in this case $F=\pm \tfrac12\sqrt{1+a^2}$.*

Comment: See as well the very interesting article published in American Mathematical Monthly (2013) generalizing what we have been doing here : http://www-personal.umd.umich.edu/~mkagarwa/AgarwalAMS.pdf

Comment: I have given some other new references inside my text.